# How to denote a measure that is defined by a density function.

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, notation

Say I have a probability density function $\alpha$ and the corresponding measure $m(A)$:= $\int_A \alpha(x) d\lambda (x)$. 
(Here $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure)
What would be the standard notation for $m?$

Thank you.

Comment: $dm=\alpha d\lambda$. There is no notation of $m$ itself.

Comment: Then I guess it would seem natural to define it as $m_\alpha$?